# How to avoid loss of input focus when nested input is bound using angularFire?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Nested input fields lose focus on update (due to a re-render of the view) when the model is bound using angularFire (behaves normally when not using angularFire). See a [detailed plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XqruZXLJ2wZ9nX2NrDRq?p=preview) which demonstrates the issue.

Can anyone suggest a workaround or a fix for this issue?

Comment: As @oori answered, seems like a regression that was introduced by the latest version of AngularFire. Follow the issue to be notified when it gets fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in the current version *(sep'2013)*.  Until it's fixed, revert back to older version, or manually add the removed block.
see: https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/121

**update:**
https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/commit/574bff119b86b16585fdaba599286c1cc7d4a892